# ASH if statement in a if statement

Tags: bash, syntax, ash

I've seen many examples with multiple conditions related to each other, but there are 2 different unrelated conditions where the second one only should happen if the first one is true.
How can I get the following nicely organised and in 1 line?

```
funtion1
if [[ $valueX == 2 ]]; then
    funtion2
    if [[ $valueY -gt 16 ]]; then
        sleep $valueZ
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Your question is tagged with both "bash" and "ash", two different shells.  The `[[` syntax is specific to bash; ash doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have it nicely organized, or you can have it in one line.

I'd say what you have now is already nicely organized.  I don't think there's any way to reorganize it in fewer lines without making it less legible.

(If the `funtion2` weren't there, you could combine the two conditions.)

If you insist on putting that entire chunk of code on line line, you can do it simply by joining the lines and adding semicolons, like this:

```
funtion1 ; if [[ $valueX == 2 ]]; then funtion2 ; if [[ $valueY -gt 16 ]]; then sleep $valueZ ; fi ; fi
```

But as I said, I don't think anyone would call this "nicely organized"; it's more difficult to read, and to maintain, than the original multi-line nicely indented version.

Note that the `[[` syntax is specific to [bash](/questions/tagged/bash); [ash](/questions/tagged/ash) doesn't support it.

(Oh, and you've misspelled "function".)

Comment: ok, thanks, I had 20 of these after one another and figures it could get more compact.. but guess not :)

Comment: @Nixx: You might still be able to reorganize the code if there's some consistent relationship among the conditions.

Comment: mhm, not sure, only function2 and valueX are equal for all 20. The other elements are different (although numbered in sequence)

Comment: At the moment I'm cleaning up my code and it tuns out that It is prefered to have everything in 1 line. How do I do this? is there a "end of line" charachter that works in all situations?

Comment: You can replace end-of-line with `;` in some cases. If you joined all your lines into one, adding semicolons *except* after the `then` lines, then it should work. But such a layout is ugly and difficult to read. *Why* is it preferred to have everything on one line?

Comment: The one line would be preferred as I attempt to hide the code which will be included in a 1 lined xml file (just not to make it stand out) inside an app-builder app i'm using :)

Comment: @Nixx: It's possible a `case` statement could make your code neater, but if you want it all on one line then neatness isn't really the goal. It's possible that other techniques could make it more *compact* however, but we'd need to see more of the code to determine that.

Comment: @Dennis: well, it turned out the app that would send out this one-lined code messes things up if the line was too long, so I gave up and kept it in 4 lines. And the full script is actually the original color-fade version :)